# Excel formula to convert number to both feet and inches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet (excel 2010) where in column A I have a metric value (2413mm) and in column B I need a formula that will convert 2413mm to show the feet/inches in the following format (7' 11")

I can do this if I use 3 or 4 columns to first convert the 2413 to 7.9', then extract the feet and inches into two separate columns and finally concatenate the separate feet and inches into a final cell.

I'd really like to be able to do all this within one cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I notice that Gary's Student's answer will give you decimals in the inches - if you want the answer to the nearest inch try this version

`=INT(ROUND(A1*0.03937,0)/12)&"' "&MOD(ROUND(A1*0.03937,0),12)&""""`

Comment: Works in Google Sheets without any modifications.

Comment: I would change the 0 in ROUND to 1 (at least) in the second instance. 
  =INT(ROUND(F6*0.03937,0)/12)&"' "&MOD(ROUND(F6*0.03937,2),12)&""""

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=INT(CONVERT(A1,"mm","ft")) & " '" &  12*(CONVERT(A1,"mm","ft")-INT(CONVERT(A1,"mm","ft"))) & """"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a User Defined Function to deal with feet and inches once and for all. I've shared the code and a downloadable VBA module here:

https://engineerstoolkit.wordpress.com/2017/03/05/dealing-with-feet-and-inches-in-excel/

If you install that, you can display the result (to any precision you desire) using the formula:
`=FtToString(A1/25.4/12)` Dividing by 25.4 converts the millimeters to inches, and dividing again by 12 converts it to feet (which is the assumed input for my formula).